# Check permissions before vue.js route loads

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js

does anyone know how to check a user's permissions before a vue.js route is rendered? I came up with a partial solution by checking permissions in the `created` stage of a component:

```
created: function () {

    var self = this;

    checkPermissions(function (result) {
        if(result === 'allowed') {
            // start making AJAX requests to return data
            console.log('permission allowed!');
        } else {
            console.log('permission denied!');
            self.$router.go('/denied');
        }   
    });
}
```

However, the issue is the entire page loads momentarily (albeit without any data) before the `checkPermission()` function gets activated and re-routes to `/denied`.

I also tried adding the same code in the `beforeCreate()` hook, but it didnt seem to have any effect.

Does anyone else have any other ideas? Note - the permissions vary from page to page.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you need is defined in Vue Router Docs as Data Fetching - https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html

So, as docs says, sometimes you need to fetch data when route is activated.

Keep `checkPermissions` in created hook, and then watch the route object:

```
watch: {
  // call again the method if the route changes
  '$route': 'checkPermissions'
}
```

A maybe more handy solution would be move logic from created hook into separated method and then call it in hook and in watch object too, as well.(Using ES6 syntax bellow)

```
export default {
  created() {
    this.checkPermissions()
  },
  watch: {
   '$route': 'checkPermissions'
  },
  methods: {
    checkPermissions() {
      // logic here
    }
  }
}
```