# Property Undefined on Vue Component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Getting an error that `project` is `undefined` when trying to render out some text using `{{project.projectSummary}}` in my ProjectContainer component. I'm guessing when the component is initialized `project` is `undefined` because it shows up in VueTools fine on my component.

[image]

So next, I try to set `v-if="resource.project"` on the parent component

```js
<template v-if="resource.project">

    <div class="resourceContainer">

        <resource-card :resource="resource" :showResourceBtn="showResourceBtn"></resource-card>
        <project-container :project="resource.project"></project-container>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
import { firebaseAuth, database } from '../../database/database'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueFire from 'vuefire'
import ResourceCard from '../ResourceCard/ResourceCard'
import ProjectContainer from './Project'

Vue.use(VueFire);

export default {
    name: 'Resource',
    components: {
        ResourceCard,
        ProjectContainer
    },
    data () {
        return {
            showResourceBtn: true
        }
    },
    computed: {
        fbUser () {
            return firebaseAuth.currentUser
        }
    },
    created () {

        // Load resource

        this.$bindAsObject('resource', database.ref('/resources/' + this.$route.params.resourceKey));

    }
}    

</script>
```

But this isn't working either. Gives me a warning in the console that `Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "project". Expected Object, got Undefined.`

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: have you tried initializing project as an empty object?

Comment: Well I can't see resource key here - I only see parent project, so try to set `v-if="project"`

Comment: `resource` is in the `created` hook.

Comment: @EricG In the parent?

Comment: Okay, I'm not very familiar with firebase, but what I think you should do is get this data from firebase when route is activated - https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/data-fetching.html , there is one of my answer that may would help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41785010/check-permissions-before-vue-js-route-loads/41785297#41785297

Comment: K. Yeah. Instead of trying to pass it as props. Adding it in the child's created hook works. Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you can't add `v-if` at the template tag of your vue file. It's probably not available in DOM. I would try to add it like this: `<div class="resourceContainer" v-if="resource.project">`

Comment: @AWolf https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Comment: @staxwell oh sorry, I've missed that one. So the v - if should work.